# How to select/unselect picture on website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few images on my site and I want to give user a possibility to select some of them.

I'm trying to do so with jQuery:

```
pic.attr('selected', 'selected');
pic.removeAttr('selected');
```

My problem is how to check (properly) which pictures (let's assume they're all `my-pic` class) were checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.mp-pic').each(function(i, obj) {
   if(obj.hasAttribute('selected')) {
      // selected

   } else {
      // Not selected

   }
});
```

Or to check whether a element has a particular attribute or not try this:

```
var attr = $(selector).attr('selected');
if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
    // Some operation
}
```

Comment: And what if I have pics = $('.my-pic') and I want to check which pics are selected? I got problems with undefined so I wondering how to do this 'properly'

Comment: It doesn't work but I changed `$(this)` to `obj` and now it works as I want. Thanks!

Comment: @user3616181 Oh ! yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute equals selector (https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

This code should get you a list of all the selected pictures

```
$(".my-pic[selected='selected']")
```

Comment: And what if I have pics = $('.my-pic') and I want to check which pics are selected? I got problems with undefined so I wondering how to do this 'properly'